# Python: How to build a historical dataframe of daily updated time series?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to make a historical dataframe with values from time series dataframe.

Today, I have df1 as below:

```
df1:
      A    B    C
0   1.0  2.0  3.0
```

Tomorrow, I will have df1 as below:

```
df1:
      A    B    C
0   1.5  2.6  3.7
```

So the output I want tomorrow is as below:

```
df2:
      A    B    C
0   1.0  2.0  3.0
1   1.5  2.6  3.7
```

I just want to keep add each day's new value from `df1` to a new dataframe `df2` so that I can make a historical dataframe with daily values. Can you help me on this? Thank you.

Comment: df2.append(df1).reset_index(drop=True)

Comment: Wen, your answer does not work. Because as I said in my question, 'df1' values are daily values (time series). If I follow your answer, I get a just same value as df1. I need to keep adding daily df1 values to a df2. Thanks.

Comment: then writing in csv , append =True

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding, you've got a source that updates once every day that you load to `df1`. Then you'd like to add that `df1` to a `df2` that stores all the values that you've seen in `df1` so far.

I'm basing my suggestion on a `df1` with the same structure as yours, but with random values. Every time you run this code, it will append those values to a text file `df2.txt` stored in the folder `c:\timeseries`.

Here we go:

---

Add a folder `C:/timeseries/` to your system. Then add an empty `.txt` file, enter the string `dates,A,B,C`, and save it as `df2.txt`.

The following snippet will take the length of that textfile and use that to build on a daily index to mimic your situation. That index will be the date for your `df1` that is otherwise filled with random numbers every time the snippet is run. And for each time the snippet is run, the data from `df1` will be appended to `df2`.

So, run this snippet once...

```
# imports
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

os.chdir('C:/timeseries/')

# creates df1 with random numbers
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(1, 3)), columns=list('ABC'))

# Read your historic values (will be empty the first time you run it)
df2 = pd.read_csv('df2.txt', sep=",")
df2 = df2.set_index(['dates'])

# To mimic your real life situation, I'm adding a timeseries with a datestamp 
# that starts where df2 ends. If df2 i empty, it starts from 01.01.2018
# Make a dummy datelist to mimic your situation
datelist = pd.date_range(pd.datetime(2018, 1, len(df2)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), periods=1).tolist()
df1['dates'] = datelist 
df1 = df1.set_index(['dates'])
df1.index = pd.to_datetime(df1.index)

df2 = df2.append(df1)
df2.to_csv('df2.txt')
print(df2)
```

... to get this output:

```
                      A    B    C
dates                    
2018-01-01 00:00:00  8.0  6.0  8.0
```

Those are the current values of `df1` and `df2` at the time being. I'm not using a random seed here, so your data will differ from mine.

Run it ten times in a row and you'll get this:

```
                       A    B    C
dates                             
2018-01-01 00:00:00  8.0  6.0  8.0
2018-01-02 00:00:00  9.0  1.0  0.0
2018-01-03 00:00:00  3.0  1.0  3.0
2018-01-04 00:00:00  4.0  7.0  6.0
2018-01-05 00:00:00  1.0  4.0  3.0
2018-01-06 00:00:00  3.0  7.0  6.0
2018-01-07 00:00:00  8.0  6.0  4.0
2018-01-08 00:00:00  4.0  7.0  0.0
2018-01-09 00:00:00  0.0  9.0  8.0
2018-01-10 00:00:00  8.0  4.0  8.0
```

In order to start from scratch, go ahead and delete all rows but the first in your df2.txt file.

I hope this is what you're looking for. If not, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Use [pd.concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html)

```
df1 = pd.concat([df1, df2])
```

or [pd.DataFrame.append](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html)

```
df1 = df1.append(df2)
```

Comment: Ray, Sorry that's not what I want. Your answer results in exactly same as Wen's answer: In other words, I get only copy of df1. What I want is to make a historical dataframe with daily values from df1. Thanks.

Comment: Are you saying df1 is a data frame that changes every day?

Comment: It is a time series dataframe. I'm not adding two dataframes on the same day. I want to keep today's values from df1, and then tomorrow, I want to add tomorrow's df1 values to yesterday's df1, making df2 a historical dataframe (I get consecutive values every day).

Comment: Yes, df1 changes everyday (time series data).

Comment: Then you need a file that keeps recording the value. Use `new_dataframe.to_csv(file_path, append=True)`

Comment: Without using excel, is there any other solution for this? Thanks.

Comment: Not to my knowledge. You have to have a placeholder (a log file or cache) for your historical data. it's like you need a database to record historical data.